# How to insert values along with auto generated field in msaccess

Tags: java, netbeans

I create a jForm in Netbeans which has 8 columns. I want to insert values of 2 to 7 fields at run time and the 1st field value should be auto incremented through the database. 
I create a table in ms access, where the first field has auto number datatype.

when i write the insert query, if i take 7 question marks , and pass values from 2 , it shows the error of " database fields values are not same".
How to do this, that frst field is autoincremented and next fields will insert the values..
Here is my code...

```
Connection myconnection= null;
        String mydriver= "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
        if((jTextField2.getText().length()==0)||(jTextArea1.getText().length()==0)||(jRadioButton1.getText().length()==0)||(jRadioButton2.getText().length()==0)||(jFormattedTextField1.getText().length()==0)||(jTextField3.getText().length()==0)||(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()==0)||(jFormattedTextField3.getText().length()==0)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please fill all the details");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Class.forName(mydriver);
                myconnection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq= C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\My Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\DAV REHABILITATION\\Davdb.accdb; Uid=Admin; Pwd=;");
                try
                {
                    String myquery= "insert into Patients values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    PreparedStatement mystatement= myconnection.prepareStatement(myquery);
                    mystatement.setString(2,jTextField2.getText());
                    mystatement.setString(3,jTextArea1.getText());
                    if(jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
                        mystatement.setString(4, "Male");
                    } else if(jRadioButton2.isSelected()) {
                        mystatement.setString(4, "Female");
                    }
                    mystatement.setString(5, jFormattedTextField1.getText());
                    mystatement.setString(6, jTextField3.getText());
                    mystatement.setString(7, jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    mystatement.setString(8, jFormattedTextField3.getText());
                    mystatement.executeUpdate();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Data Saved");
                    mainform obj=new mainform();
                    this.setVisible(false);
                    obj.setVisible(true);

                } 
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error in Query. " + e.getMessage());
                }


        }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, " Error Occured.Connection wrong" + e.getMessage());
            }


        }



    }
```

Comment: do you want to insert only 2 values ?

Comment: specify the fieldnames to insert to : `insert into Patients(field2,field3,...`

Answer (score 1):

> How to do this, that frst field is autoincremented and next fields will insert the values

You don't, instead, specify the columns you want to insert into (and the order)

```
String myquery= "insert into Patients (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

mystatement.setString(1,jTextField2.getText());
mystatement.setString(2,jTextArea1.getText());
if(jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
    mystatement.setString(3, "Male");
} else if(jRadioButton2.isSelected()) {
    mystatement.setString(3, "Female");
}
mystatement.setString(4, jFormattedTextField1.getText());
mystatement.setString(5, jTextField3.getText());
mystatement.setString(6, jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
mystatement.setString(7, jFormattedTextField3.getText());
mystatement.executeUpdate();
```

Where `columnX` is the name of the column

The number use use in the `setX` method indicates the value for the placeholder  in the query

See [The SQL INSERT INTO statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) for more details

Answer (score 0):

your table is containing total `8` columns.

your query is wrong

```
String myquery= "insert into Patients values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";//only 7 indexes
```

You must write `respective column names` since you are not entering all the column values here.

```
   String myquery= "insert into Patients(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Since you are passing values to only `7` columns and you are not entering a value to your first column in your table. 
Here `col1`, `col2`, etc are your table column names whose values you are suppose to insert.

Comment: it works, but it is starting the auto number field by 3.

Comment: previously you may entered some values

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753505/mysql-id-auto-increment-doesnt-starts-from-0 @ShainaGupta